# Unable to switch to Iframe in Gmail using Selenium webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-extension, webdriver, gmail

This is for an `iframe` injected into `Gmail`, I am unable to switch to this frame any help is highly appreciated.

HTML Code:

```
<iframe src="chrome-extension://fcinnggknmdfkilogcndkgpojpfojeem/src/iframe.html" id="Hiver_iframe_content" style="width: 100%; height: 263px; position: absolute; top: 60px; z-index: 4; border: none; display: none;"></iframe>
```

What I am trying to do :

```
driver.switchTo().frame("Hiver_iframe_content");
```

used to work perfectly fine a few days back..!!

Comment: <iframe src="chrome-extension://fcinnggknmdfkilogcndkgpojpfojeem/src/iframe.html" id="Hiver_iframe_content" style="width: 100%; height: 263px; position: absolute; top: 60px; z-index: 4; border: none; display: none;"></iframe>

Comment: Can you consider elaborating a bit what you mean by `for an iframe injected into Gmail`? Thanks

Comment: Hiver is a Gmail extension , wherein functionality works within Gmail as an Iframe

Comment: Great !!! Can you consider showing us your work please? Thanks

Comment: Hi you can try our product at hiverhq.com

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way of switching frame what you are trying like

```
driver.switchTo().frame("Hiver_iframe_content");
```

You have to pass webElement or Index of frame while switching

Try this and let me know

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("Hiver_iframe_content")));
```

OR

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);  // 0 is index of frame
```

Comment: Thanks Ive tried it before and tried it now as well i get this :  NoSuchFrameException: no such frame: element is not a frame

Comment: Doesnt work i get an error : NoSuchFrameException: no such frame: element is not a frame

Comment: Ive tried the following  
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
      WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 90); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("Hiver_iframe_content"));
      driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("Hiver_iframe_content")));
neither of these work

Comment: This is specific to an iframe being loaded inside of Gmail

Comment: Nope just in case selenium was confused :)

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the frame to load using explicit wait as given below.

WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 90);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("Hiver_iframe_conten"));

Try and let me know.

Thanks,
Murthi. S

Comment: Thanks for the reply it doesnt work :( seems like gmail has changed the way iframes are loaded inside it

Answer (score 0):

try using switching to frame WebElement as below:

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe#Hiver_iframe_content")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears that along with the release of New login for Gmail google released a new version of chrome driver , i fixed my issue by upgrading my chromedriver version

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to switch to iframe which you mentioned. As a matter of fact there is not a single iframe but two iframes you have to switch. see the code below:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();//First switch to default content
driver.switchTo().frame("Hiver_iframe_content");//Switch to 1st iframe
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe_handler");//Switch to 2nd iframe
```

P.s-This code now works for our automation and we're able to access v2 from iframe itself :-)